# Adding elements to an pool array in python inside of an function

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, append, web-crawler

I want to code an webcrawler where I need to add links from the pages to the array inside of the pool, but the pool only works with the given urls and doesn't work with the appended links I give it in the def function.

```
from concurrent import futures
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen



def linksSearchAndAppend(url):
    req = Request(url)
    html_page = urlopen(req)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

    links = []
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        if link[0]=="/":
            link[0]==""
            link=url+link

    global urls
    urls.append(links)
    print (urls)
    



urlListend=open("urlList.txt", "r")
urls=[]
for line in urlListend:
    urls.append(line.rstrip())
urlListend.close()
#main multithreading is working
e = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
for url in urls:
    e.submit(linksSearchAndAppend, url)
e.shutdown()
```

Comment: as far as I see the linkSearchAndAppend function isn't even called

Answer (score 0):

```
from concurrent import futures
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen



def linksSearchAndAppend(url):
    req = Request(url)
    html_page = urlopen(req)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
    #print (soup)
    links = []
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        #if link[0]=="/":
        #    link[0]==""
        #    link=url+link

    global urls
    urls.append(links)
    print (links)
    



urlListend=open("urlList.txt", "r")
urls=[]
for line in urlListend:
    urls.append(line.rstrip())
urlListend.close()
#main multithreading is working
e = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
for url in urls:
    e.submit(linksSearchAndAppend, url)
e.shutdown()
```

Comment: It still doesn't work with the append part, but outcommented the if case this works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works but it would still need an "alreadysearchedUrls" array so that it doesn't repeat the search of the already search "urls"

```
from concurrent import futures
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen



def linksSearchAndAppend(url):
    req = Request(url)
    html_page = urlopen(req)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
    #print (soup)
    links = []
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        #if link[0]=="/":
        #    link[0]==""
        #    link=url+link

    global urls
    urls.append(links)
    print (urls)
    



urlListend=open("urlList.txt", "r")
urls=[]
for line in urlListend:
    urls.append(line.rstrip())
urlListend.close()
#main multithreading is working
for i in urls:

    e = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
    for url in urls:
        e.submit(linksSearchAndAppend, url)
    e.shutdown()
```

Comment: I still don't know how to add elements inside of a pool by a running process, but found a workaround this way I guess